# updating a sublist value in suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Please note that I realize there is an existing question similar to this but my issue is I can't set the text field in the list but I can the other.... No errors happen.

I have the following suitescript code.  When I run the function to fire the client script function (based on a user event button push)  My checkbox field gets updated(checked) but the text field does not seem to do anything at all.   Am I doing something wrong?
User event Script

```
function onRequest(context){

                var form = ui.createForm({ title: 'Batch Printing' });
                form.clientScriptModulePath = "./PrintSuiteletClient.js"

               var sublist = form.addSublist({
                    id: 'custpage_itemfulfillments',
                    type: ui.SublistType.LIST,
                    label: 'Item Fulfillments'
                });
                var field =  sublist.addField({
                    id: 'custpage_internalid',
                    label: 'ID',
                    type: ui.FieldType.TEXT
                });

                sublist.addField({
                    id: 'custpage_rec_print',
                    label: 'PRINT',
                    type: ui.FieldType.CHECKBOX
                });

                sublist.addField({
                    id : 'custpage_type',
                    type : ui.FieldType.TEXT,
                    label : 'Type'
                });
// later wire to the onPrintSelected client side 
   }
```

client script.js

```
    function onPrintSelected(scriptContext) {
               console.log("on mark all")
              var sourceLineCount = 
         pageContext.currentRecord.getLineCount({sublistId:'custpage_itemfulfillments'});
            var curRec = pageContext.currentRecord
            try {
                for (x = 0; x < sourceLineCount; x++) {
                    var lineNum = curRec.selectLine({
                        sublistId: 'custpage_itemfulfillments',
                        line: x
                    });
            

// WORKS//-----
                    curRec.setCurrentSublistValue({  
                        sublistId: 'custpage_itemfulfillments',
                        fieldId: 'custpage_rec_print',
                        value: true,
                        ignoreFieldChange: true
                    });
// DOES NOT SET or ERROR
                    curRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'custpage_itemfulfillments',
                        fieldId: 'custpage_type',
                        value: "TEST",
                        ignoreFieldChange: false
                    });
            
                    curRec.commitLine({
                        sublistId: 'custpage_itemfulfillments'
                    });
            
                }
            }
            catch (ex)
            {
                console.log('error')
            }
              
        
      }
```

Comment: What is `curRec`? As I can see you store the record object in `currentRecord` variable. Ig you are using `setCurrentSublistValue` in wrong variable(which is holding record object) and try to enclose the code in try catch block to catch error.

Comment: Thanks for the mention....My error.   That was not a direct copy paste of the whole fn.   I changed the var to show it should all be curRec.    And there is a try catch in my code (no exception happens).   Last I wanted to note that in fact the first line does work to mark the checkbox column correctly...   Just not the text one

Comment: Can you remove `ignoreFieldChange` parameter and test it once again. Sometimes it works. If you can directly copy paste `onPrintSelected()` function it will be more helful and are you using `onFieldChange()` of client script ?

Comment: Is this client script is called by Suitelet or User Event.

Comment: This is called by a button pushed event on a suitelet. (acting as a  user event of sorts).  Changing that ignoreFieldChange does not do anything different.  It still did not update that field.   I do not use onFieldChange (i did add it and put a simple log statement in it and it is not firing) but also keep in mind that that is a sublist that would be changing.   I added an on sublist change event to it and the event is not firing off as the code is)

Comment: Why don't you log the error?
It will be easier to show us the error

Comment: There is no error, it is just that nothing happens.   The call goes through but with no effect to the screens list.  When i said 'that was my error" I had meant that I had originally posted with an incorrect variable in my example.